# What is the purpose of greater than or equal to?

Tags: php

`>=`

Why use the above and not just the greater than but with one number less.

For example:
`> 8`
Is the same as
`>= 9`

I know it's not a huge deal, but it just seems to serve no purpose to me.

FYI I'm still fairly beginner with PHP so I'm asking a lot of 'why's' at the moment

Comment: Sometimes semantics matter

Comment: If using variables `>= $var` would become `> $var-1`, why?

Comment: If the number you are evaluating comes from a variable,  you would have to do if ($var+1 > 8), which is visually less obvious

Comment: Why does mathematics use `>=` and `<=`.... did you ever ask your math teacher in school?

Comment: Wait till you read about `=`, `==` and `===`.

Comment: Simple, comparisons don't only work on integers

Answer (score 1):

Let's use an example where you want to cover the left side of the equation being greater than or equal to data input by a user or coming from another variable (something where you don't actually have a hardcoded number).

Your options are `$value >= $input` or `$value > ( $input - 1 )`

Very often when writing software, you won't have a specific number in mind. Values change. Writing production software is more about logic than it is math.

Answer (score 1):

How would you represent any number greater or equal to 1? If your logic was true, then `$value > 0` would be enough, but if we are dealing with decimals, then `0.95` would be greater than `0` and this `0.95>0` would equate to `TRUE` while `0.95 >= 1` would equate to false.

You might then follow up your question with "What if we are only using integers and not decimals?". Then in that case mathematically you are correct in assuming that the logic would be the same in most situations (I say most because to say something is ALWAYS true in programming is a dangerous statement to make).

However, in practical terms, `>=` is more visual and clear to most, and if for some reason you had to change your code in the future to take decimals into account, your site would have a costly error.